# Iterate through an Object key in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, object

I am trying to iterate through a dynamic Object with key. Actually, my goal is to save each element of the arrays of those 2 Object keys all together into an array. How can I do it? 
My code:

```
private object: {
    [key: string]: string[];
  } = {}; 

{Product: Array(9), Brand: Array(7)}
    where Product: (9) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    where Brans: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

`< ES 2017:`

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  let value = obj[key];
});
```

`>= ES 2017:`

```
Object.entries(obj).forEach(
  ([key, value]) => console.log(key, value);
);
```